# jQuery reduce the width from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a DIV that has a width of 500px.

I am trying to reduce the width with an animation from 500px to 0px and from 0px to 500px again.

There is only a problem, that the DIV is reduced starting from the right to the left.

I want the opposite thing.

From the start the width will be reduced and animated from left to right, and then will be increased from 0px to 500px starting from right to left.

How can I do it with jQuery?

Thanks for any help

**EDITED**

```
function animateText(px) {
  $('#slidetext').animate({
   'width' : px
  });
 }
```

Comment: Just added my little snippet of jQuery code

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Comment: use **style="position:absolute;** on the Image

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you'll need to use `position: absolute`, see my Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/An7K4/1/)

```
function animateText(px) {
    $('#slidetext').animate({
       left: $("#slidetext").width(),
       width: px
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying for this

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/WQGvE/1/)

```
$("#div2").animate({
          'width':'50%',
          'left':'49%'
},1000);​
```

Answer (score 0):

see this example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TC9Mn/

The idea is to wrap your element inside a a container with `position: relative` and assign to the element you want to animate `position: absolute` and `right: 0`

in this way the width changes from left to right

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this can be done using `css3` without using any javascript/jquery code. The below is my fiddle.
using `@keyframe` and `animation` property
http://jsfiddle.net/eQMyq/2/

Comment: Did that work for you in IE? Did for me in Chrome, but not in IE :)

Comment: Ah scratch that, @keyframes are everything **BUT IE** http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_keyframes.asp

Comment: see this link once http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/